# Inserting more than one point into Influx DB on a single from command prompt

Tags: influxdb

From a windows command prompt i'm attempting to enter 2 points on a single line, but I always get a parsing error.

If I try to separate the points with a \r\n, I get the same parse error

> INSERT temperature,location=cityname value=-6.01 1575378000temperature,location=cityname value=-5.99 1575381600

ERR: {"error":"unable to parse 'temperature,location=cityname value=-6.01 1575378000temperature,location=cityname value=-5.99 1575381600': bad timestamp"}

Anyone have any experience with doing multi point inserts?

---

Update: using a file as input with curl

```
.$ curl -i -XPOST 'http://myserver:8086/write?db=testing' --data-binary @example.txt
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json
Request-Id: f005e1c8-1613-11ea-82ff-00155d0968c8
X-Influxdb-Build: OSS
X-Influxdb-Error: unable to parse 'temperature,location=cityname value=-6.00 1575378000 ': bad timestamp unable to parse 'temperature,location=cityname value=-5.00 1575381600 ': bad timestamp
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.7.7
X-Request-Id: f005e1c8-1613-11ea-82ff-00155d0968c8
Date: Tue, 03 Dec 2019 21:29:07 GMT
Content-Length: 189

{"error":"unable to parse 'temperature,location=cityname value=-6.00 1575378000\r': bad timestamp\nunable to parse 'temperature,location=cityname value=-5.00 1575381600\r': bad timestamp"}

example.txt file contents:
temperature,location=cityname value=-6.00 1575378000
temperature,location=cityname value=-5.00 1575381600
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no multiple points in the INSERT clause.

You have to either use separate INSERTS (what's the issue with that, by the way? why would you insist to have it it in a single clause?)

Or use batches of line protocol records another way ([like this](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/tools/shell/#import-data-from-a-file-with-import), or send it through REST endpoint).

Comment: thanks. i will take your suggestion of doing through REST.

Comment: how to do i setup the file? currently if i enter more than a single line i get parsing errors.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "the file" here? How exactly you intend to use it? And please show how that "file" looks like.

Comment: "Line protocol accepts the newline character \n and is whitespace-sensitive" - cite from the l.p. syntax doc. Get rid of '\r'-s & excess whitespaces, should be fine then.

Comment: So i'm using c++ to create the example.txt file, and the loop terminates each line with: '\n'. When i open the example.txt file in notepad++ the lines end in CRLF. I think that's parsing of the file fails.